# Add legend to bar + line ggplot chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot with variables A (bars) and B (line) where **legend is not showing**. I have a couple of questions I'd like a hand with please:

- Legend is not showing.
- Location (x-axis) is only showing 3 of the 7

  My data:

)

```
Location <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
A <- c(0.81, 0.94, 2.31, 12.2, 11.52, 4.7, 10.13)
B <- c(3304, 97025, 187012, 25962, 383875, 96233, 227291)

df = data.frame(Location, A, B)
```

My code:

```
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_col(aes(Location, A), color = "black", fill = "tan1") +
    geom_line(aes(Location, B/40000), size = 1.5, color="black") +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*40000))
```

Trying to add the legend:

```
+ theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2))+
        scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("A" = "grey")) +
        scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("B" = "black")) +

        theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to make sure you have `color` in your `aes` to create the legend.

Also added `guides` to remove the fill from the black line in legend.

You can add `breaks` to `scale_x_continuous` to show all x-axis labels, if that's what you were looking for.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(Location, A, color = "A"), fill = "tan1") +
  geom_line(aes(Location, B/40000, color = "B"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*40000)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7) +
  #theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2))+
  #scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("A" = "grey")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("A" = "tan1", "B" = "black")) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=c("tan1", NA))))
```

[image: plot with legend]